# Plantronics BT headphone sound output problem after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, bluetooth, 22.04, a2dp

After Ubuntu upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 my Plantronics BT headphone do not play/output sound, though they are set as default Output Device in Sound settings. I tried to repair them and set different configurations A2DP Sink and HFP, but the sound still go to laptop speakers. What could be the problem?

dmesg logs

```
[41657.738285] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000bd1f5e6a submission failed (90)
[41657.738289] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[41657.748494] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
```

bt status

```
Mai 08 22:57:11 precision bluetoothd[1247]: src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
Mai 08 22:57:26 precision bluetoothd[1247]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_BC_F2_92_BE_D9_20/sep2/fd0: fd(45) ready
Mai 08 23:21:35 precision bluetoothd[1247]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
```

Comment: Same issue here and now